# Java For loop !!! printing out values

Tags: java, for-loop

Write a program that generates a sequence of 20 random die tosses in an array and
that prints the die values, marking only the longest run, like this:
1 2 5 5 3 1 2 4 3 (2 2 2 2) 3 6 5 5 6 3 1
If there is more than one run of maximum length, mark the first one.

I am working on this question and this code works till count the maxCount.
However, I am stuck in printing out the final result which means I am working on the last for loop to print out what the question requires.
But, the result is not what I wanted to get. How can I figure it out?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class AA {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 1;
    int maxCount = 1;
    int runEndsAt = 0;

    // create array
    int[] num = new int[20];
    // create random object
    Random numbers = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        num[i] = numbers.nextInt(6) + 1;
        // added 1 b/c it starts from 0
    }

    boolean inRun = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        if (inRun) {
            if (num[i] != num[i - 1]) {
                /*
                 * System.out.print("|" + count +"|");
                 * System.out.print(") ");
                 */ inRun = false;

            }
            if (inRun) {
                System.out.print("|" + count + "|");
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (!inRun) {
            if (count > maxCount) {
                maxCount = count;
                runEndsAt = i;
            }
            count = 1;
            if (i < 19)
                // comparing index from i to i+1
                if (num[i] == num[i + 1]) {
                System.out.print("( ");
                inRun = true;
                }
        }
    }
    if (inRun) {
        /*
         * System.out.print("|" + count +"|"); System.out.print(" )");
         */ }

    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        if (i == runEndsAt - maxCount) {

            System.out.println("(");

            if (i == runEndsAt) {
                System.out.println(")");

            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: It's great you got the code block (frequently people don't), but look at the formatting of the code itself and ask yourself if that's readable. (Hint: No, not even remotely.) Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Also, create an example that doesn't use "Random", but still has the error you're trying to debug.  Then delete every line of code that isn't related to the error.  You should be able to get it down to 20 lines of code (or thereabouts), at which point you may even be able to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I tried to fix the code readable.

Comment: @DanielPark How hard did you try?

Comment: @DanielPark ever IDE has a keyboard shortcut allowing to format/indent a whole file at once. Use it.

Comment: I tried to use tap at eclipse to put more indentation. Does it work for you?

Comment: No. This is not formatted properly **at all**. Use Cmd-shift-F (on Mac), Ctrl-Shift-F (on Windows/Linux). If in doubt, open the Help menu, and search for "Format".

Comment: @JBNizet I figured it out! thx, I learned how to use indentation properly from you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Java - you may want to use StringBuilder.
Solution:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class LongestRun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // We are told that die tosses is an Array... so we create one.
        int[] tosses = IntStream.range(0, 20)
                        .map(i -> { return (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1); } )
                        .peek(System.out::print)
                        .toArray();

        // Counting and generation of output:
        int length = 0, longest = 0, startPos = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(""+tosses[0]);
        for (int i=1; i<tosses.length; i++) {
            if (tosses[i-1] == tosses[i]) {
                length++;
            } else {
                length=0;
            }

            if (longest < length) {
                longest = length;
                startPos = i-length;
            }
            sb.append("" + tosses[i]);
        }
        sb.insert(startPos+longest+1, ")");
        sb.insert(startPos, "(");

        // Final result:
        System.out.println("Result:");
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a fun problem. Here is my solution:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class SO_40307704 {
  private final static int NUM_ROLLS = 100;
  private final static Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\d)(\\1)+");

  public static void main(String... args) {
    final Random r = new Random();
    final String rolls = Stream.generate(() -> r.nextInt(6) + 1)
        .limit(NUM_ROLLS)
        .map(i -> Integer.toString(i))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
    Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(rolls);
    int start = 1;
    int end = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
      if (m.end() - m.start() > end - start) {
        end = m.end();
        start = m.start();
      }
    }
    System.out.println(String.format(
        "%s(%s)%s",
        rolls.substring(0, start),
        rolls.substring(start, end),
        rolls.substring(end)));
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I am sure it works, but why using Regex to count numbers?

Comment: If your data can be encoded as a string, and you're looking for patterns (not parsing), then regular expressions may make for eloquent code. In this case the conditions were met, and the code looked readable.